# How to pass the input field value using the href in html?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to pass a integer value from href to the input field value.  
Assume example.com is the webpage which has 1 input field. 
i want to do something like
href="www.example.com" value="12345" click here 1 
href="www.example.com" value="125"click here 2 
if user clicks **click here 1** then the input field in example.com must fill with 12345 value
if user clicks **click here 2** then the input field in example.com must fill with 125 value. (User no need to enter the value)

Comment: You should try something yourself first. What have you tried so far, using your own research?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5yjp93bd/

Answer (score 0):

Alright so from my understanding this is what you want to do -
You have TWO LINKS

Link 1 - Click me!
Link 2- no, Click me!

If a user clicks on Link 1, they will be shown an input field that has a value. The input value will be link one's value. If link 2 is clicked, they will be shown an input field with link two's value.

It's fairly simple to achieve this, just set up a simple javascript function that occurs when each link is clicked.

For example
`const linkOne = document.querySelector('.linkOne'); const inputOne = document.querySelector('.inputOne'); linkOne.addEventListener("click", function() { inputOne.value = linkOne.getAttribute('value'); });`
and then you would do the same for link two.

The getAttribute can help you get any attribute for an element, we wouldn't use .value because that would return the the link.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, you have several options such as vanilla JavaScript or use the **[jQuery library](https://jquery.com/)** like in the code snippet I am sharing with you and the result will be the same.

If you run this snippet, you will notice that when the user clicks in any of the links, the **Input** is automatically filled with the values you provided in the request description. Please go ahead and implement this on your code, but don't forget to add the jquery library to your html main file in order for you to use it.

I certainly hope this helps, fellow. Have a good day and keep coding, it is a great adventure!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickHere01").click(function() {
      $("#txtValues").val("12345");
    });
    
    $("#clickHere02").click(function() {
      $("#txtValues").val("125");
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<h3>Welcome to the www.example.com website</h3>
<p>Please click the below links to fill up this textbox:<br />
    <input type="text" id="txtValues" value="">
</p>

<a href="#" id="clickHere01">Click here 1</a>
<a href="#" id="clickHere02">Click here 2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you ..... but if I want to create 100 links then it becomes a very lengthy code. Is there a simple solution for that?

Comment: Hi there,

Your request was never to create this for a 100 links, hence I answered what you've asked on the post, however, if that is the case, and although is NOT recommended to handle the DOM like that, you could use a for loop to create the 100 links with jQuery. This article speaks about the process to create an anchor tag using jQuery. I certainly hope this helps with your case, Yashwanth. https://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery-tutorials/create-anchor-tag-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Look for my sample: This is what you want?

```js
$("#btn_1").on("click",function(){
    $("#data_1").val($(this).val());
});
$("#btn_2").on("click",function(){
    $("#data_1").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button id="btn_1" value="12345">Click here 1</button>
    <button id="btn_2" value="125">Click here 2</button>
    
    <input id="data_1" type="text" value="" readonly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you will do it. In HTML create two buttons Click here 1 and Click here 2 give them the function names showResult1 and showResult2 in attribute onmousedown and create an input with the id "answer" then in Script tag define two variables a and b and assign them your integer values 12345 and 125 and create a two functions with the name you defined in html in onmousedown attributes of two buttons "showResult1" "showResult2" and get the Id "answer" of the input through document.getElementById and give them a value of a and b

```js
var a = 12345;
var b = 125;

function showResult1() {
  document.getElementById("answer").value = a;
}

function showResult2() {
  document.getElementById("answer").value = b;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onmousedown="showResult1()">Click here 1</button>

<button id="btn" onmousedown="showResult2()">Click here 2</button>
<br><br>
<input id="answer" readonly>
```